# Bootstrap Input Slider - very basic setup

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-slider

I'm trying for a very basic setup for a bootstrap'ish input slider and somehow I cant get it to work.

**What I want:**

[image]

**What I get:**

[image]

**Source / Working example / Tutorial:**

http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/

**My code / source / error:**

```
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.9.0/css/bootstrap-slider.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


</head>
<body>

<input id="ex1" data-slider-id='ex1Slider' type="text" data-slider-min="-5" data-slider-max="20" data-slider-step="1"
       data-slider-value="14"/>


<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#ex1').slider({
        formatter: function (value) {
            return 'Current value: ' + value;
        }
    });
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.9.0/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note:**

I pull all the basic components (CSS/JS): bootstrap, bootstrap-slider and JQuery from the web repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I fixed it for you. https://jsfiddle.net/k5k9aa70/

Your scripts were executing out of order and `slider` wasn't recognized as a function.

Comment: thank you very much - to be honest I never heard of anything like 'scripts executing out of order' :-( woah...

Comment: just think of it like one long script starting at the top. If your trying to load slider without it being initialized then that's a problem.